# Extent of Java Object Storage & Proper Implementation of Objects

Tags: java

So I was practicing with java a little bit, creating a text adventure game and ended up with a question that I was curious about.

I understand that in a method all variables declared are local, but is it possible to make them visible to the class itself?

Look at this code for example,

```
public class GameMain {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      GameMain game = new GameMain();
      game.itemInit();
      Entity test = new Entity("Test", 10, 5, 5, 10, helm_nothing, body_nothing, weapon_nothing, offhandweapon_nothing);
   }
   public void itemInit() {
      helm_s1_init();
      body_s2_init();
      main_s3_init();
      offhand_s4_init();
   }
   public void helm_s1_init() {
      Armor helm_nothing = new Armor("Nothing", 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
      //more here
   }
   public void body_s2_init() {
      Armor body_nothing = new Armor("Nothing", 0, 0, 2, 0, 0);
      //more here
   }
   public void main_s3_init() {
      Weapon weapon_nothing = new Weapon("Nothing", 0, 0, 3, 0, 0);
      //more here
   }
   public void offhand_s4_init() {
      Weapon offhandweapon_nothing = new Weapon("Nothing", 0, 0, 4, 0, 0);
      //more here
   }
}
```

I know that this code would work if I moved the contents of the initialization methods into main, but I wanted to be able to organize my data into separate methods that are easy to look at.

The problem in this code is that when declaring the new Entity, helm_nothing, body_nothing, weapon_nothing, and offhandweapon_nothing are all deleted once itemInit() is done, but I am looking for a way to prevent that from happening so the Entity may be successfully created.

Secondly, is this the best way of going around implementing this sort of information? How else could I do it in perhaps a nicer manner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Actually you should move those variables as attributes of the class, this would be into `GameMain`. In this way these attributes would represent the state of the object `GameMain`.
And the init methods you call, operate on the state of the object.

When doing this, the attributes will exist as long as the `game` variable in `main` exists.

For the Test, you can have *getter()* methods that would provide the attributes you need to the outside of the `GameMain` object.

```
public class GameMain {

   private  Armor helm_nothing;
   private  Armor body_nothing
   private Weapon weapon_nothing;
   private Weapon offhandweapon_nothing;


   public Armor getHelmNothing(){
      return this.helm_nothing();
   }

   // put getters for the other attributes here

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      GameMain game = new GameMain();
      game.itemInit();
      Entity test = new Entity("Test", 10, 5, 5, 10, game.getHelmNothing(), game.getBodyNothing(), game.getWeaponNothing(), game.getOffhandWeaponNothing());
   }
   public void itemInit() {
      helm_s1_init();
      body_s2_init();
      main_s3_init();
      offhand_s4_init();
   }
   public void helm_s1_init() {
      helm_nothing = new Armor("Nothing", 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
      //more here
   }
   public void body_s2_init() {
      body_nothing = new Armor("Nothing", 0, 0, 2, 0, 0);
      //more here
   }
   public void main_s3_init() {
      weapon_nothing = new Weapon("Nothing", 0, 0, 3, 0, 0);
      //more here
   }
   public void offhand_s4_init() {
      offhandweapon_nothing = new Weapon("Nothing", 0, 0, 4, 0, 0);
      //more here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your methods could also return an object:

```
public class GameMain {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      GameMain game = new GameMain();
      Entity test = game.itemInit();
   }

   public Entity itemInit() {
      Armor helm_nothing = helm_s1_init();
      Armor body_nothing = body_s2_init();
      Weapon weapon_nothing = main_s3_init();
      Weapon offhandweapon_nothing = offhand_s4_init();
      return new Entity("Test", 10, 5, 5, 10, helm_nothing, body_nothing, 
              weapon_nothing, offhandweapon_nothing);
   }
   public Armor helm_s1_init() {
      Armor helm_nothing = new Armor("Nothing", 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
      //more here
      return helm_nothing;
   }
   public Armor body_s2_init() {
      Armor body_nothing = new Armor("Nothing", 0, 0, 2, 0, 0);
      //more here
      return body_nothing;
   }
   public Weapon main_s3_init() {
      Weapon weapon_nothing = new Weapon("Nothing", 0, 0, 3, 0, 0);
      //more here
      return weapon_nothing;
   }
   public Weapon offhand_s4_init() {
      Weapon offhandweapon_nothing = new Weapon("Nothing", 0, 0, 4, 0, 0);
      //more here
      return offhandweapon_nothing;
   }
}
```